# Changing CNN to work with 3D convolutions

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network, niftynet

I am working with code from [here](https://github.com/zhengliz/natural-adversary) ([paper here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.11342.pdf)) that creates a GAN. I am trying to apply this to a new domain, switching from their application on MNIST to 3D brain MRI images. My issue is in the defining of the GAN itself.

For example, their code for defining the generative model (takes noise of dimension z_dim and produces an image from the MNIST distribution, so 28x28) is this, with my comments based on how I believe it works:

```
def generate(self, z):
    # start with noise in compact space
    assert z.shape[1] == self.z_dim

    # Fully connected layer that for some reason expands to latent * 64
    output = tflib.ops.linear.Linear('Generator.Input', self.z_dim,
                                     self.latent_dim * 64, z)
    output = tf.nn.relu(output)
    # Reshape the latent dimension into 4x4 MNIST
    output = tf.reshape(output, [-1, self.latent_dim * 4, 4, 4])

    # Reduce the latent dimension to get 8x8 MNIST
    output = tflib.ops.deconv2d.Deconv2D('Generator.2', self.latent_dim * 4,
                                         self.latent_dim * 2, 5, output)
    output = tf.nn.relu(output)  # 8 x 8
    # To be able to get 28x28 later?
    output = output[:, :, :7, :7]  # 7 x 7

    # Reduce more to get 14x14
    output = tflib.ops.deconv2d.Deconv2D('Generator.3', self.latent_dim * 2,
                                         self.latent_dim, 5, output)
    output = tf.nn.relu(output)  # 14 x 14

    output = tflib.ops.deconv2d.Deconv2D('Generator.Output',
                                         self.latent_dim, 1, 5, output)
    output = tf.nn.sigmoid(output)  # 28 x 28

    if self.gen_params is None:
        self.gen_params = tflib.params_with_name('Generator')

    return tf.reshape(output, [-1, self.x_dim])
```

And this is my code using niftynet convolutional layers, where z_dim and latent_dim are the same as before at 64, and I've added the results of the print statements:

```
def generate(self, z):
    assert z.shape[1] == self.z_dim

    generator_input = FullyConnectedLayer(self.latent_dim * 64,
                acti_func='relu',
                #with_bn = True,
                name='Generator.Input')
    output = generator_input(z, is_training=True)

    print(output.shape) # (?, 4096)
    #output = tflib.ops.linear.Linear('Generator.Input', self.z_dim,
    #                                 self.latent_dim * 64, z)
    #output = tf.nn.relu(output)
    output = tf.reshape(output, [-1, self.latent_dim * 4, 1, 18, 18])  # 4 x 4

    print(output.shape) # (?, 256, 1, 18, 18)

    generator_2 = DeconvolutionalLayer(self.latent_dim*2,
                    kernel_size=5,
                    stride=2,
                    acti_func='relu',
                    name='Generator.2')
    output = generator_2(output, is_training=True)
    #output = tflib.ops.deconv2d.Deconv2D('Generator.2', self.latent_dim * 4,
    #                                     self.latent_dim * 2, 5, output)
    #output = tf.nn.relu(output)  # 8 x 8
    print(output.shape) # (?, 512, 2, 36, 128)
    #output = output[:, :, :-1, :-1]  # 7 x 7

    generator_3 = DeconvolutionalLayer(self.latent_dim,
                    kernel_size=5,
                    stride=2,
                    acti_func='relu',
                    name='Generator.3')
    output = generator_3(output, is_training=True)
    #output = tflib.ops.deconv2d.Deconv2D('Generator.3', self.latent_dim * 2,
    #                                     self.latent_dim, 5, output)
    #output = tf.nn.relu(output)  # 14 x 14

    print(output.shape) # (?, 1024, 4, 72, 64)

    generator_out = DeconvolutionalLayer(1,
                    kernel_size=5,
                    stride=2,
                    acti_func='sigmoid',
                    name='Generator.Output')
    output = generator_out(output, is_training=True)

    #output = tflib.ops.deconv2d.Deconv2D('Generator.Output',
    #                                     self.latent_dim, 1, 5, output)
    #output = tf.nn.sigmoid(output)  # 28 x 28

    if self.gen_params is None:
        self.gen_params = tflib.params_with_name('Generator')

    print(output.shape) # (?, 2048, 8, 144, 1)
    print("Should be %s" % str(self.x_dim)) # [1, 19, 144, 144, 4]

    return tf.reshape(output, self.x_dim)
```

I am not really sure how to be able to get the 19 in there. Currently I get this error.

> ValueError: Dimension size must be evenly divisible by 2359296 but is 1575936 for 'Reshape_1' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [?,2048,8,144,1], [5] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1](https://github.com/zhengliz/natural-adversary) = [1,19,144,144,4].

I am also relatively new to building NNs and I also have a few questions. What is the point of the latent space when we already have a compact representation in z-space? How do I decide the size of the "output dimension" i.e. the second parameter in the layer constructor?

I have also been looking at a successful implementation of a CNN with [here](https://github.com/taigw/brats17/blob/master/util/MSNet.py) for inspiration.
Thank you!

***Major edit:***

I made some progress and got tensorflow to run the code. However, even with a batch size of 1, I am running into an out of memory error when I try to run the training operation. I calculated one image to have the size 19 * 144 * 144 * 4 * 32 (bits per pixel) = ~50 MB so it is not the data that is causing the memory error. Since I basically just tweaked the GAN parameters until it worked, my issue is probably in there. Below is the whole file.

```
class MnistWganInv(object):
    def __init__(self, x_dim=784, z_dim=64, latent_dim=64, batch_size=80,
                 c_gp_x=10., lamda=0.1, output_path='./'):
        self.x_dim = [-1] + x_dim[1:]
        self.z_dim = z_dim
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.c_gp_x = c_gp_x
        self.lamda = lamda
        self.output_path = output_path

        self.gen_params = self.dis_params = self.inv_params = None

        self.z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.z_dim])
        self.x_p = self.generate(self.z)

        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=x_dim)
        self.z_p = self.invert(self.x)

        self.dis_x = self.discriminate(self.x)
        self.dis_x_p = self.discriminate(self.x_p)
        self.rec_x = self.generate(self.z_p)
        self.rec_z = self.invert(self.x_p)

        self.gen_cost = -tf.reduce_mean(self.dis_x_p)

        self.inv_cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.x - self.rec_x))
        self.inv_cost += self.lamda * tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.z - self.rec_z))

        self.dis_cost = tf.reduce_mean(self.dis_x_p) - tf.reduce_mean(self.dis_x)

        alpha = tf.random_uniform(shape=[self.batch_size, 1], minval=0., maxval=1.)
        difference = self.x_p - self.x
        interpolate = self.x + alpha * difference
        gradient = tf.gradients(self.discriminate(interpolate), [interpolate])[0]
        slope = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(gradient), axis=1))
        gradient_penalty = tf.reduce_mean((slope - 1.) ** 2)
        self.dis_cost += self.c_gp_x * gradient_penalty

        self.gen_params = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='Generator')
        self.inv_params = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='Inverter')
        self.dis_params = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='Discriminator')

        self.gen_train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(
            learning_rate=1e-4, beta1=0.9, beta2=0.999).minimize(
            self.gen_cost, var_list=self.gen_params)
        self.inv_train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(
            learning_rate=1e-4, beta1=0.9, beta2=0.999).minimize(
            self.inv_cost, var_list=self.inv_params)
        self.dis_train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(
            learning_rate=1e-4, beta1=0.9, beta2=0.999).minimize(
            self.dis_cost, var_list=self.dis_params)

    def generate(self, z):
        print(z.shape)
        assert z.shape[1] == self.z_dim

        with tf.name_scope('Generator.Input') as scope:
            generator_input = FullyConnectedLayer(self.latent_dim * 4 * 3 * 18 * 18,
                        acti_func='relu',
                        #with_bn = True,
                        name='Generator.Input')(z, is_training=True)

        print(generator_input.shape)
        #output = tflib.ops.linear.Linear('Generator.Input', self.z_dim,
        #                                 self.latent_dim * 64, z)
        #output = tf.nn.relu(output)
        generator_input = tf.reshape(generator_input, [-1, 3, 18, 18, self.latent_dim * 4])  # 4 x 4

        print(generator_input.shape)

        with tf.name_scope('Generator.2') as scope:
            generator_2 = DeconvolutionalLayer(self.latent_dim*2,
                            kernel_size=5,
                            stride=2,
                            acti_func='relu',
                            name='Generator.2')(generator_input, is_training=True)
        #output = tflib.ops.deconv2d.Deconv2D('Generator.2', self.latent_dim * 4,
        #                                     self.latent_dim * 2, 5, output)
        #output = tf.nn.relu(output)  # 8 x 8
        print(generator_2.shape)

        with tf.name_scope('Generator.3') as scope:
            generator_3 = DeconvolutionalLayer(self.latent_dim,
                            kernel_size=5,
                            stride=2,
                            acti_func='relu',
                            name='Generator.3')(generator_2, is_training=True)
        #output = tflib.ops.deconv2d.Deconv2D('Generator.3', self.latent_dim * 2,
        #                                     self.latent_dim, 5, output)
        #output = tf.nn.relu(output)  # 14 x 14

        print(generator_3.shape)

        with tf.name_scope('Generator.Output') as scope:
            generator_out = DeconvolutionalLayer(4,
                            kernel_size=5,
                            stride=2,
                            acti_func='sigmoid',
                            name='Generator.Output')(generator_3, is_training=True)

        #output = tflib.ops.deconv2d.Deconv2D('Generator.Output',
        #                                     self.latent_dim, 1, 5, output)
        #output = tf.nn.sigmoid(output)  # 28 x 28

        if self.gen_params is None:
            self.gen_params = tflib.params_with_name('Generator')

        print(generator_out.shape)
        generator_out = generator_out[:, :19, :, :, :]
        print(generator_out.shape)
        print("Should be %s" % str(self.x_dim))

        return tf.reshape(generator_out, self.x_dim)

    def discriminate(self, x):
        input = tf.reshape(x, self.x_dim)  # 28 x 28

        with tf.name_scope('Discriminator.Input') as scope:
            discriminator_input = ConvolutionalLayer(self.latent_dim,
                            kernel_size=5,
                            stride=2,
                            acti_func='leakyrelu',
                            name='Discriminator.Input')(input, is_training=True)

        #output = tflib.ops.conv2d.Conv2D(
        #    'Discriminator.Input', 1, self.latent_dim, 5, output, stride=2)
        #output = tf.nn.leaky_relu(output)  # 14 x 14
        with tf.name_scope('Discriminator.2') as scope:
            discriminator_2 = ConvolutionalLayer(self.latent_dim*2,
                            kernel_size=5,
                            stride=2,
                            acti_func='leakyrelu',
                            name='Discriminator.2')(discriminator_input, is_training=True)

        #output = tflib.ops.conv2d.Conv2D(
        #    'Discriminator.2', self.latent_dim, self.latent_dim * 2, 5,
        #    output, stride=2)
        #output = tf.nn.leaky_relu(output)  # 7 x 7
        with tf.name_scope('Discriminator.3') as scope:
            discriminator_3 = ConvolutionalLayer(self.latent_dim*4,
                            kernel_size=5,
                            stride=2,
                            acti_func='leakyrelu',
                            name='Discriminator.3')(discriminator_2, is_training=True)

        #output = tflib.ops.conv2d.Conv2D(
        #    'Discriminator.3', self.latent_dim * 2, self.latent_dim * 4, 5,
        #    output, stride=2)
        #output = tf.nn.leaky_relu(output)  # 4 x 4
        discriminator_3 = tf.reshape(discriminator_3, [-1, self.latent_dim * 48])

        with tf.name_scope('Discriminator.Output') as scope:
            discriminator_out = FullyConnectedLayer(1,
                            name='Discriminator.Output')(discriminator_3, is_training=True)

        #output = tflib.ops.linear.Linear(
        #    'Discriminator.Output', self.latent_dim * 64, 1, output)
        discriminator_out = tf.reshape(discriminator_out, [-1])

        if self.dis_params is None:
            self.dis_params = tflib.params_with_name('Discriminator')

        return discriminator_out

    def invert(self, x):
        output = tf.reshape(x, self.x_dim)  # 28 x 28

        with tf.name_scope('Inverter.Input') as scope:
            inverter_input = ConvolutionalLayer(self.latent_dim,
                        kernel_size=5,
                        stride=2,
                        #padding='VALID',
                        #w_initializer=self.initializers['w'],
                        #w_regularizer=self.regularizers['w'],
                        #b_initializer=self.initializers['b'],
                        #b_regularizer=self.regularizers['b'],
                        acti_func='leakyrelu',
                        #with_bn = True,
                        name='Inverter.Input')

        #output = tflib.ops.conv2d.Conv2D(
        #    'Inverter.Input', 1, self.latent_dim, 5, output, stride=2)
        #output = tf.nn.leaky_relu(output)  # 14 x 14

            output = inverter_input(output, is_training=True)

        with tf.name_scope('Inverter.2') as scope:
            inverter_2 = ConvolutionalLayer(self.latent_dim*2,
                        kernel_size=5,
                        stride=2,
                        acti_func='leakyrelu',
                        name='Inverter.2')

            output = inverter_2(output, is_training=True)

        #output = tflib.ops.conv2d.Conv2D(
        #    'Inverter.2', self.latent_dim, self.latent_dim * 2, 5, output,
        #    stride=2)
        #output = tf.nn.leaky_relu(output)  # 7 x 7

        with tf.name_scope('Inverter.3') as scope:
            inverter_3 = ConvolutionalLayer(self.latent_dim*4,
                        kernel_size=5,
                        stride=2,
                        acti_func='leakyrelu',
                        name='Inverter.3')

            output = inverter_3(output, is_training=True)

        #output = tflib.ops.conv2d.Conv2D(
        #    'Inverter.3', self.latent_dim * 2, self.latent_dim * 4, 5,
        #    output, stride=2)
        #output = tf.nn.leaky_relu(output)  # 4 x 4
        output = tf.reshape(output, [-1, self.latent_dim * 48])

        with tf.name_scope('Inverter.4') as scope:
            inverter_4 = FullyConnectedLayer(self.latent_dim*8,
                        acti_func='leakyrelu',
                        #with_bn = True,
                        name='Inverter.4')

            output = inverter_4(output, is_training=True)

        #output = tflib.ops.linear.Linear(
        #    'Inverter.4', self.latent_dim * 64, self.latent_dim * 8, output)
        #output = tf.nn.leaky_relu(output)
        with tf.name_scope('Inverter.Output') as scope:
            inverter_output = FullyConnectedLayer(self.z_dim,
                        acti_func='leakyrelu',
                        #with_bn = True,
                        name='Inverter.Output')

            output = inverter_output(output, is_training=True)

        #output = tflib.ops.linear.Linear(
        #    'Inverter.Output', self.latent_dim * 8, self.z_dim, output)
        output = tf.reshape(output, [-1, self.z_dim])

        if self.inv_params is None:
            self.inv_params = tflib.params_with_name('Inverter')

        return output

    def train_gen(self, sess, x, z):
        _gen_cost, _ = sess.run([self.gen_cost, self.gen_train_op],
                                feed_dict={self.x: x, self.z: z})
        return _gen_cost

    def train_dis(self, sess, x, z):
        _dis_cost, _ = sess.run([self.dis_cost, self.dis_train_op],
                                feed_dict={self.x: x, self.z: z})
        return _dis_cost

    def train_inv(self, sess, x, z):
        _inv_cost, _ = sess.run([self.inv_cost, self.inv_train_op],
                                feed_dict={self.x: x, self.z: z})
        return _inv_cost

    def generate_from_noise(self, sess, noise, frame):
        samples = sess.run(self.x_p, feed_dict={self.z: noise})
        for i in range(batch_size):
            save_array_as_nifty_volume(samples[i], "examples/img_{0:}.nii.gz".format(n*batch_size + i))
        #tflib.save_images.save_images(
        #    samples.reshape((-1, 28, 28)),
        #    os.path.join(self.output_path, 'examples/samples_{}.png'.format(frame)))
        return samples

    def reconstruct_images(self, sess, images, frame):
        reconstructions = sess.run(self.rec_x, feed_dict={self.x: images})
        comparison = np.zeros((images.shape[0] * 2, images.shape[1]),
                              dtype=np.float32)
        for i in range(images.shape[0]):
            comparison[2 * i] = images[i]
            comparison[2 * i + 1] = reconstructions[i]
        for i in range(batch_size):
            save_array_as_nifty_volume(comparison[i], "examples/img_{0:}.nii.gz".format(n*batch_size + i))
        #tflib.save_images.save_images(
        #    comparison.reshape((-1, 28, 28)),
        #    os.path.join(self.output_path, 'examples/recs_{}.png'.format(frame)))
        return comparison


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--z_dim', type=int, default=64, help='dimension of z')
    parser.add_argument('--latent_dim', type=int, default=64,
                        help='latent dimension')
    parser.add_argument('--iterations', type=int, default=100000,
                        help='training steps')
    parser.add_argument('--dis_iter', type=int, default=5,
                        help='discriminator steps')
    parser.add_argument('--c_gp_x', type=float, default=10.,
                        help='coefficient for gradient penalty x')
    parser.add_argument('--lamda', type=float, default=.1,
                        help='coefficient for divergence of z')
    parser.add_argument('--output_path', type=str, default='./',
                        help='output path')
    parser.add_argument('-config')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    config = parse_config(args.config)
    config_data = config['data']

    print("Loading data...")
    # dataset iterator
    dataloader = DataLoader(config_data)
    dataloader.load_data()
    batch_size = config_data['batch_size']
    full_data_shape = [batch_size] + config_data['data_shape']
    #train_gen, dev_gen, test_gen = tflib.mnist.load(args.batch_size, args.batch_size)

    def inf_train_gen():
        while True:
            train_pair = dataloader.get_subimage_batch()
            tempx = train_pair['images']
            tempw = train_pair['weights']
            tempy = train_pair['labels']
            yield tempx, tempw, tempy

    #_, _, test_data = tflib.mnist.load_data()
    #fixed_images = test_data[0][:32]
    #del test_data

    tf.set_random_seed(326)
    np.random.seed(326)
    fixed_noise = np.random.randn(64, args.z_dim)
    print("Initializing GAN...")
    mnistWganInv = MnistWganInv(
        x_dim=full_data_shape, z_dim=args.z_dim, latent_dim=args.latent_dim,
        batch_size=batch_size, c_gp_x=args.c_gp_x, lamda=args.lamda,
        output_path=args.output_path)

    saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=1000)

    with tf.Session() as session:
        session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        images = noise = gen_cost = dis_cost = inv_cost = None
        dis_cost_lst, inv_cost_lst = [], []
        print("Starting training...")
        for iteration in range(args.iterations):
            for i in range(args.dis_iter):
                noise = np.random.randn(batch_size, args.z_dim)
                images, images_w, images_y = next(inf_train_gen())

                dis_cost_lst += [mnistWganInv.train_dis(session, images, noise)]
                inv_cost_lst += [mnistWganInv.train_inv(session, images, noise)]

            gen_cost = mnistWganInv.train_gen(session, images, noise)
            dis_cost = np.mean(dis_cost_lst)
            inv_cost = np.mean(inv_cost_lst)

            tflib.plot.plot('train gen cost', gen_cost)
            tflib.plot.plot('train dis cost', dis_cost)
            tflib.plot.plot('train inv cost', inv_cost)

            if iteration % 100 == 99:
                mnistWganInv.generate_from_noise(session, fixed_noise, iteration)
                mnistWganInv.reconstruct_images(session, fixed_images, iteration)

            if iteration % 1000 == 999:
                save_path = saver.save(session, os.path.join(
                    args.output_path, 'models/model'), global_step=iteration)

            if iteration % 1000 == 999:
                dev_dis_cost_lst, dev_inv_cost_lst = [], []
                for dev_images, _ in dev_gen():
                    noise = np.random.randn(batch_size, args.z_dim)
                    dev_dis_cost, dev_inv_cost = session.run(
                        [mnistWganInv.dis_cost, mnistWganInv.inv_cost],
                        feed_dict={mnistWganInv.x: dev_images,
                                   mnistWganInv.z: noise})
                    dev_dis_cost_lst += [dev_dis_cost]
                    dev_inv_cost_lst += [dev_inv_cost]
                tflib.plot.plot('dev dis cost', np.mean(dev_dis_cost_lst))
                tflib.plot.plot('dev inv cost', np.mean(dev_inv_cost_lst))

            if iteration < 5 or iteration % 100 == 99:
                tflib.plot.flush(os.path.join(args.output_path, 'models'))

            tflib.plot.tick()
```

Comment: I'll try to write up what I can when I get a chance, but one thing to check out is deconv3d and conv3d instead of 2d.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using niftynet which as far as I know is developed for this kind of imaging, so I believe their deconv and conv layers are 3D by default? https://niftynet.readthedocs.io/en/dev/niftynet.layer.html

Comment: [This](https://github.com/meetshah1995/tf-3dgan) might be what you are looking for

Comment: @Kyranstar Can you draw up a full overlook of the conv net? Sort of like the way it's done here: https://neurohive.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/AlexNet-1.png 
It would just save a lot of time looking through code to determine whereabouts the memory error is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely trying to optimize more parameters than your machine can can handle in memory.  You're on the right track with decreasing the batch size, but for better or worse, it might not be something you're doing wrong.

Each of your convolutional layers has parameters based on the kernel width, input layers, and output layers.  Here's an article describing dimensionality analysis for CNN's: https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-and-calculating-the-number-of-parameters-in-convolution-neural-networks-cnns-fc88790d530d

What could be causing you a lot of trouble however is the number of additional parameters you have to optimize when you flatten everything and start using fully connected layers.  Each value in the current vector gets another parameter to optimize for every number of nodes you're using in the fully connected layer.

If your initial image vector is quite large (it is in your case) you're going to end up with a *lot* of parameters in your fully connected layers.  It looks like you're using strides > 1, so the dimensionality gets reduced a good bit.  However, as your problem stands right now, it will likely take some heavy duty hardware to solve.

One idea is to try reducing the dimensionality of your input images or the dimensionality of the internal representation through increasing the stride length when pooling.